# Generic class to derive from its generic type parameter

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, metaprogramming

Compiles:

```
public class SerializableObject<T> implements Serializable
{
 public T m_object;
}
```

Does NOT compile:

```
public class SerializableObject<T> extends T implements Serializable
{
}
```

So, I want a generic class to derive from its generic type parameter.
Why?
Let's say I have a `Map<K, V>` and I simply want to serialize it.
I also don't know ahead which keys I'll have.

How do I do that?

Comment: If you can define the `K` and `V` elsewhere (e.g. on a class that contains the map), wouldn't `<K extends Serializable>` be sufficient?

Comment: This makes no sense.  You can't serialize an object of a class that wasn't meant to be serialized just by slapping the interface on it.  The developer of the class has to foresee this (marking fields as transient, making sure other fields are serializable etc).

Comment: @Joeri +1 for "slapping the interface on it" LOL! Asking doesn't hurt, you might be sureprised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, I want a generic class to derive from its generic type parameter.

You just can't do that, I'm afraid. There are various technical reasons for this, not least of which is type erasure.

You should look for an alternative solution to your issues - this idea is a dead end.

Comment: As a curious sidenote: is this possible in .NET/C#? It doesn't use erasure, but I guess it still won't work there either.

Comment: @Joachim: Nope, .NET doesn't allow it either.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, your goal is near a Dynamic type, which java does not support.

Comment: Maybe. The first example works while the second doesn't. They should allow it. And no, it's not dynamic actually, as it compiles before runtime.

Comment: If you don't know Who <T> is, how could you extend it? The compiler would go nuts.

<T> could have abstract methods, or even be a final class.