# Alternative solutions to derive class generic from a type parameter

Tags: scala, generics

I would like to create a generic allowing me to reuse some functions for mutliple classes. Ideally my design would be:

```
class ColoredMesh[T <: Mesh] extends T
{
  def Color(color:ColorRGBA) = {
    val vertices = super.getVertexCount
    // do something
  }
}

class ColoredSphere extends ColoredMesh[Sphere]

class ColoredCylinder extends ColoredMesh[Cylinder]
```

However, this gives compile errors:

> Error:(7, 38) class type required but T found
>
> class ColoredMesh[T <: Mesh] extends T

Similar Java question [Generic class to derive from its generic type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760776/java-generic-class-to-derive-from-its-generic-type-parameter) resulted in an answer deriving from a generic type parameter is not possible for technical reasons. I guess this applies for Scala as well. Is there some other common design pattern how to solve this?

Comment: Type parameter is useless there, it's meant to express inheritance, as seens in @gzm0 answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use traits and mix-in composition:

```
trait ColoredMesh extends Mesh {
  def Color(color:ColorRGBA) = {
    val vertices = super.getVertexCount
    // do something
  }
}

class ColoredSphere extends Sphere with ColoredMesh
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `trait` with a self-type:

```
trait Colored { self: Mesh =>
    def Color(color: ColorRGBA) = {
        self.getVertexCount
        //do something
    }
}

class ColoredSphere extends Sphere with Colored
```